# QML: How can I change dynamically label in legend in ChartView?

Tags: qt, user-interface, qml

For a ChartView I have declared a simple LineSeries:

```
LineSeries {
        id: lineSeries1
        name: varName
        axisX: axisX
        axisY: axisY1
    }
```

I want the name to be able to be changed when clicked. How can I do it? Thank you!

Comment: Ehmm ... `onClicked: lineSeries1.name="newname"`?

Comment: @folibis Maybe I was not really clear in my question. I want the name to be kind of text input, so I can click the text, it will be highlighted and I will be able to change it.